# Update of DependencyProperty value not updating bound ViewModel

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have user control with a custom dependency property...

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageKeyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ImageKey", typeof(string), typeof(ImageSelector),
                 new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                        OnImageKeyPropertyChanged));

public string ImageKey
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ImageKeyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ImageKeyProperty, value); }
}


private static void OnImageKeyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageSelector imageSelector = d as ImageSelector;
        if (imageSelector == null) return;

        if (e.NewValue == null || e.NewValue.ToString() == "")
        {
            imageSelector.Image.Source = null;
            imageSelector.buttonSelect.Content = "select...";
            imageSelector.Image.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            imageSelector.Image.Source = ImageLibrary.GetImage(e.NewValue.ToString());
            imageSelector.buttonSelect.Content = "change...";
            imageSelector.Image.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        imageSelector.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(imageSelector, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ImageKey"));
    }

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageSelectWindow w = new ImageSelectWindow();
        w.ShowDialog();
        if (w.DialogResult.HasValue && w.DialogResult.Value)
        {
            this.ImageKey = w.SelectedImageKey;
        }
    }
```

If I bind a ViewModel (that is the DataContext) to it...

```
<myControl ImageKey={Binding Image} />
```

Shouldn't I be able to programmatically set the ImageKey value in the custom UserControl and have the bound ViewModel property get updated? Apparently not, cause it's not working.

What am I missing? !?!?

Comment: How & where, are you updating ImageKey programmatically ? Can you share that code portion. It may be, you were updating ImageKey before it gets binded.

Comment: show code for OnImageKeyPropertyChanged

Comment: I added the code for OnImageKeyPropertyChanged  and to show how the value is programmatically changed. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"Shouldn't I be able to programmatically set the ImageKey value ...?"

Short answer: Er... no.
Sorry, this is ages ago, but just in case someone finds it and wonders.

Here you are binding:

```
<myControl ImageKey={Binding Image} />
```

Here you are destroying your binding:

```
this.ImageKey = w.SelectedImageKey;
```

In very short, no, you cannot update a bound property programmatically. Update its bound value instead:

```
(this.DataContext as MyViewModel).Image = w.SelectedImageKey;
```

Have fun.